# How to accommodate insertion of new line of code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code below which builds/creates a description based on the Value field (where contains data) in sequential order.  For example, I have a table which has the following fields...
Item
Classification
Attribute Name
Value
UOM
Status

What I'm trying to do is insert a line of code that will only build the description from the Value field (where contains data) where the Status field = Active.  The Status field info is either "Active" Or "Foreign". Currently, if the Status field shows "Foreign" the code will also build the description for these records which I just learned should not be included.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Again, below is the code...

```
Sub SD()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsMara, rs_cou As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs, rs2, x As DAO.Recordset
Dim SD, strAttribute, strValue, sdvalue As String
Dim seq, d, count1 As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb

db.Execute ("UPDATE Item_Template SET Description = '', Long_Description = '';")
Set rsMara = db.OpenRecordset("select * from [Item_Template] order by [Item]")

While Not rsMara.EOF
If rsMara.Fields("Classification") & "" <> "" Then
SD = UCase(rsMara.Fields("Classification")) & ": "
seq = 1
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from All_Item_Attributes where [Item] = '" & rsMara.Fields("Item") & "' and [Value] & '' <> '' order by [Item],[Sequence (Cls Attribute Mapping)]")

While Not rs.EOF
If (rs.Fields("UOM") Like "IN*" Or rs.Fields("UOM") Like "O*") Then
     SD = SD & rs.Fields("Value") & " " & UCase(rs.Fields("UOM")) & ", "
Else
     SD = SD & rs.Fields("Value") & " " & UCase(rs.Fields("UOM")) & ", "
End If
rs.MoveNext
Wend
        SD = Trim(SD)
        rsMara.Edit
        SD = Trim(Mid(SD, 1, Len(SD) - 1))
        rsMara.Fields("Description") = Trim(SD)
        rsMara.Fields("Description") = Replace(rsMara.Fields("Description"), " ,", ", ")
        rsMara.Fields("Description") = Replace(rsMara.Fields("Description"), "  ", " ")
        rsMara.Update
End If
DoEvents
rsMara.MoveNext
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim rsMara, rs_cou As DAO.Recordset` - only `rs_cou` is a `DAO.Recordset`.  `rsMara` is a `variant`.  You need to use `Dim rsMara  As DAO.Recordset, rs_cou As DAO.Recordset`.  Same with the other variable declarations.

Comment: I've always wondered about this - doesn't Access complain when you create a field called `Value`?  Mine whinges like hell with a `...is a reserved word.....`

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected results - it looks like there should be a much easier way than your code seems to indicate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which table the field `Status` is in.
You have two lines of code opening recordsets so it will be one of these lines of code:

```
Set rsMara = db.OpenRecordset("select * from [Item_Template] WHERE Status='Active' order by [Item]")
```

or

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from All_Item_Attributes where [Item] = '" & rsMara.Fields("Item") & "' and [Value] & '' <> '' AND Status='Active' order by [Item],[Sequence (Cls Attribute Mapping)]")
```

Basically adding `Status='Active'` into the `WHERE` clause.  This won't work if your `Status` field is a lookup field in which case you'd need to use the *Foreign Key* value that links it to your Status type table.  `Status=1` for example.

Comment: The table where the data is originating from is call All_Item_Attributes and is a "linked" table.  The data is first being appended to the Item_Template table then the code is builds off the Item_Template data.  Problem is the "Status" field is not getting appended to the Item Template...I assume I need to append that field and "update" the code with your updates?  Sorry, I'm a newbie when it comes to coding, but really want to learn.

Comment: So you have two tables - `All_Item_Attributes`, `Item_Template`.  You set `Description` and `Long_Description` to zero length strings on all records in `Item_Template` (probably better to use `Null` rather than `''`).  You then return everything from `All_Item_Attributes`where the `Item` field is equal to that in the other table and the `Value` field holds a zero length string?  You then step through each record and where the UOM field starts with `IN` or `O` you add the `Value` and `UOM` field to the `SD` (variant) variable.  Looks like you should be able to join the tables.